# (select pname +''+ comment from table)......returns all zero values despite of table containing data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select pname +''+ comment from table
```

after executing above query it returns result containing all zero values why?

Comment: If either `pname` or `comment` are `NULL`, the resulting value would be `NULL`.  Use `Coalesce(PName, '') + '' + Coalesce(Comment, '')` instead.

Comment: both column contains data

Comment: Then you need to show some sample data, the results you're getting, and your desired results..   We can neither see your screen nor read your mind.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLEOV.png

Comment: above image contains result that i am getting

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcUk.png

Comment: this one contains table data i want to manipulate

Comment: desired output..... i want to combine both pname and comment column under single column using AS .. is that possible ?

Comment: `+` in mysql is a mathematical operator, it does not concat strings.

Comment: got you @BrianGlaz :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use concat()

```
select concat(pname, ' ' , comment ) from my_table;
```

Comment: don't need to used concate .. i think

Comment: concat is the basic concatenation function for mysql  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: because using + on string returns zero ... i tried it on integer values it returns sum of both columns @RïshïKêshKümar

Comment: @RakeshSaini  .. `select pname,' ',comment from table;`   try this

Answer (score 0):

**As Simple its also work without `concate funtion`**

```
SELECT pname+ ' ' + comment as ProductDetails FROM my_table;
```

> **Reference :**  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column2&ss=-1

Comment: it worked.... but it doesn't combine both column into one which was desired.. so i think concat is the only way to do that right?

Comment: `SELECT  pname+ ' ' + comment   as ProductDetails
FROM my_table;`

Comment: @RakeshSaini Try this.. i hope you get what actually trying to do.

Comment: Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column2&ss=-1

Comment: satisfied with the reference provided by you....but why the same is not happening in my case (mysql 5.5.21 and oracle EE) ?